# Fragment transition?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

Any help would be great with my issue. Basically I'm using [this](http://javatechig.com/android/navigation-drawer-android-example) tutorial and its a web view fragment. So I got rid of the `WebView` and made new activities. My issue is connection the activities with the drawer so then every thing goes to a different activity. Once again, any idea on how to do this would be helpful.

Comment: That's the problem. I don't know what to look for and so fourth. @AntiVeeranna

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend this tutorial instead.

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

I've used it and I have a functioning application at the moment. You can download the source, change the text and images if you'd like.